# .NET core 5 ProtectedData Exception in Worker service once published as Window Service

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, password-protection, password-encryption

I have a .NET core 5 Worker service.  On my own PC I can "dotnet run" and use the application no problem.  However, once I publish the service (following [MS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service))
and register the Windows service, then I see the following error in Window event log on start up:

> Log Name:      Application
> Source:        .NET Runtime Date:          8/25/2021 3:58:40 PM Event
> ID:      1026 Task Category: None Level:         Error Keywords:
> Classic User:          N/A Computer:      HD52E Description:
> Application: DataUploader.Service.exe CoreCLR Version:
> 5.0.921.35908 .NET Version: 5.0.9 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException:
> The system cannot find the path specified.    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.ProtectOrUnprotect(Byte[]
> inputData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope, Boolean
> protect)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[]
> encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
> at DataUploader.Service.Worker.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> stoppingToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
> host)    at DataUploader.Service.Program.Main(String[] args)

This is the line that protected the plaintext in the config file:

```
var protectedSecret = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiSecret), null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

and this is line that's trying to unprotect it at run time:

```
ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(configuration["ApiPassword"]), null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

Update: Here is the updated Program.cs as requested:

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            var command = args[0];
            if (command == "--init-secret")
            {
                SetApiSecret();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid command.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
    }

    private static void SetApiSecret()
    {
        var apiId = ReadLine.Read("Api Login Id: ");
        var apiSecret = ReadLine.ReadPassword("Api Password: ");
        var protectedSecret = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiSecret), new byte[] {44, 23, 125, 17}, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        var configJson = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json"));
        configJson["ApiUserName"] = apiId;
        configJson["ApiPassword"] = Convert.ToBase64String(protectedSecret);
        File.WriteAllText("appsettings.json", configJson.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you. The credentials have been encrypted and saved in the config file.");
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService(options =>
            {
                options.ServiceName = "Data Uploader Service";
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

Along with the Worker class:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private string apiSecret;

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var unProtectedSecret = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(configuration["ApiPassword"]), new byte[] { 44, 23, 125, 17 }, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        apiSecret = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(unProtectedSecret);

        return base.StartAsync(stoppingToken);
    }}
```

Comment: Could you please share your Program.cs implementation?

Comment: Wondering is the config isn't being loaded properly, which can be a side-effect of running as a service. Just to be sure, try adding appsettings explicitly in CreateDefaultBuilder(). Something like .UseWindowsService().ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder => { configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true); })

Comment: Update: I changed the last argument to DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine.  When then plaintext was encrypted it was being done under the CurrentUser - i.e. when the application is run in a console window.  Later when it runs as a Windows service and tries to read the encrypted text it runs as Local System - which I suspect is the core of the issue.  Changing to LocalMachine fixed (or worked around?) the issue.  Mind you the error about a file not being found is totally ambiguous.